# AJAX Calendar Extender onchange event

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using an AJAX Calendar Extender as the calendar component in my project. And I need to call some javascript function on change of the date..
I am using onclientdateselectionchanged event to do this and it works fine.
But the problem is it works only If I select the date from the calendar using mouse.
If I enter the date manually then the javascript function is not getting called..Can you please suggest how to call the function, if I enter the date manually also.
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: you definitly should put some more effort in describing your problem and what you are actually using. With this information you cannot expect any help. WTH is onclientdateselectionchanged; What is an AJAX Calendar Extender?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have solved this one way or another long ago, but I ran into this today while searching for (what turns out to be my answer:) onclientdateselectionchanged. Since you helped me find my answer, here is yours.

To handle the case where the user manually enters date info, just apply another handler for "onkeyup" event.  Example:

```
  txtLastName.Attributes.Add("OnKeyUp", "OnFormFieldChanged();");
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to switch to jQuery UI Datepicker, you won't regret:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/